# How to publish a Spark ML pyspark.ml.PipelineModel object in code repositories?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I would like to publish a `pyspark.ml.PipelineModel` object in a Model Integration code repository. I tried to follow the [Supervised Learning Tutorial](https://paloma.palantirfoundry.com/docs/foundry/model-integration/tutorial-intro/) in the documentation, but that tutorial is for an `sklearn` model and works with `pandas` dataframes. I would like to update the approach to work with `spark` dataframes as input and produce `PipelineModel` objects to be used elsewhere in Foundry as the output.

The `pyspark` model logic I've used works -- I've run it successfully in Code Workbooks -- so I suspect the issue I'm having is with the `adapter.py` Model Adapter file.

### Data

I created a toy dataset in a Code Workbook transform, built it, and referenced it within the model repository.

```
def toy_data():
    
    import pandas as pd

    pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "x1":["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
        "x2":["z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v", "z", "v"],
        "y":[1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 11, 17, 13, 12, 17, 22, 21, 7, 14, 10]
    })

    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

    return spark_df
```

### Code logic

Here is the logic in the `model_training.py` file.

```
from transforms.api import transform, Input
from palantir_models.transforms import ModelOutput
from main.model_adapters.adapter import ExampleModelAdapter


@transform(
    training_data_input=Input("INPUT_PATH"),
    model_output=ModelOutput("MODEL_OUTPUT_PATH"),
)
def compute(training_data_input, model_output):
    '''
        This function has only Foundry specific functionality.
        It extracts the training data, calls train_model to train a model, and saves the trained model to Foundry.
    '''
    training_df = training_data_input.dataframe()     # Load a Spark dataframe from the TransformsInput

    model = train_model(training_df)               # Train the model

    # Wrap the trained model in a ModelAdapter
    foundry_model = ExampleModelAdapter(model)     # Edit ExampleModelAdapter for your model

    # Publish and write the trained model to Foundry
    model_output.publish(
        model_adapter=foundry_model
    )


def train_model(training_df):

    from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorAssembler
    from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Pipeline
    from pyspark.ml.regression import DecisionTreeRegressor
    from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
    from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder

    train_set = training_df
    cat_vars = ['x1', 'x2']

    # Pipeline components
    indexer = StringIndexer(inputCols=cat_vars, 
                            outputCols=[var + "_indexed" for var in cat_vars],
                            handleInvalid='keep')
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[var + "_indexed" for var in cat_vars], outputCol='features')

    decision_tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(featuresCol='features', labelCol='y', seed=123)

    # regression evaluator for model performance
    regression_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol='y')

    # Set pipeline
    pipeline=Pipeline(stages=[
        indexer,
        assembler,
        decision_tree])

    # Define hyperparameter grid
    params = (
        ParamGridBuilder()
        .addGrid(param=decision_tree.maxDepth, values=[1, 2])
        .addGrid(param=decision_tree.minInstancesPerNode, values=[1, 2, 3])
        .build()
    )

    # Define cross validator and extract best model
    cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline, estimatorParamMaps=params, evaluator=regression_evaluator, numFolds=2, seed=477)
    cv_trees = cv.fit(train_set)
    best_model = cv_trees.bestModel

    return best_model
```

### Model Adapter

Here's the logic for `adapter.py`. Note that I do intend the model input to be a Spark Dataframe, and the model output to be a Spark Dataframe that has been transformed by the `PipelineModel` object.

```
import palantir_models as pm
from palantir_models_serializers import DillSerializer


class ExampleModelAdapter(pm.ModelAdapter):

    @pm.auto_serialize(
        # TODO: Fill in the model constructor and define parameter serialization.
        model=DillSerializer()
    )
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model


    @classmethod
    def api(cls):
        # TODO: Edit this method to define the model API.
        inputs = {
            "df_in": pm.Spark()
        }
        outputs = {
            "df_out": pm.Spark()
        }
        return inputs, outputs

    def predict(self, df_in):
        # Input signature should match inputs defined in api()
        # Return type should match the output type defined in api()

        # TODO: Apply custom inference logic
        df_in = self.model.transform(df_in)
        return df_in
```

### Error output

Here is the resulting error when I try to build the model.

```
[module version: 1.1008.0]

TypeError: cannot pickle 'socket' object

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/transforms/_build.py", line 393, in run
    self._transform.compute(ctx=transform_context, **parameters)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/transforms/api/_transform.py", line 304, in compute
    self(**kwargs)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/transforms/api/_transform.py", line 217, in __call__
    return self._compute_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/work-dir/__user_code_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/main/model_training/model_training.py", line 32, in compute
    model_output.publish(
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/palantir_models/models/_writable_model.py", line 111, in publish
    model_adapter.save(state_writer)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/palantir_models/models/_model_adapter.py", line 136, in save
    serializers[arg_name].serialize(SubdirectoryModelStateWriter(arg_name, state_writer), arg_value)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/palantir_models_serializers/serializers/dill.py", line 19, in serialize
    self.dill.dump(obj, dill_file, recurse=True)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 252, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol, **_kwds).dump(obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 420, in dump
    StockPickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 487, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1217, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 971, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 997, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 931, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 955, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1217, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 971, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 997, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1217, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 971, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 997, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1217, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 971, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 997, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 710, in save_reduce
    self._batch_appends(listitems)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 955, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 603, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 717, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 560, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 1217, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 971, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 997, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/app/work-dir/__environment__/__SYMLINKS__/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 414, in save
    StockPickler.save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/pickle.py", line 578, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/app/work-dir/__python_runtime_environment__/__SYMLINKS__/python/socket.py", line 272, in __getstate__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot pickle {self.__class__.__name__!r} object")
TypeError: cannot pickle 'socket' object
```

### Module versions

```
Library name
python
Latest version
3.12.2
Layout
CONDA
Size
30.8MB

Library name
transforms
Latest version
1.1040.0
Layout
CONDA

Library name
transforms-expectations
Latest version
0.363.0
Layout
CONDA
Size
23.9KB

Library name
transforms-verbs
Latest version
0.363.0
Layout
CONDA
Size
28.2KB

Library name
palantir_models
Latest version
0.1040.0
Layout
CONDA
Size
37.1KB

Library name
palantir_models_serializers
Latest version
0.1040.0
Layout
CONDA
Size
4.1KB

Library name
dill
Latest version
0.3.8
Layout
CONDA
Size
86.1KB

Library name
setuptools
Latest version
69.1.1
Layout
CONDA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of March 5, 2024 this is currently not possible with models in Foundry. SparkML models need to serialize the models to a shared hadoop path, which model adapters do not have access to.

You can however, serialize model files to a dataset like the below example.

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output


@transform(
    training_data_input=Input("INPUT_PATH"),
    model_output=Output("/path/to/spark/model/dataset"),
)
def compute(training_data_input, model_output):
    training_df = training_data_input.dataframe()
    model = train_model(training_df)
    path = model_output.filesystem().hadoop_path + '/spark_model'
    model.write().overwrite().save(path)
```

Which can then be later used for inference like:

```py
from transforms.api import transform, Input, Output
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel


@transform(
    inference_input_dataset=Input("INPUT_PATH"),
    model_input=Input("/path/to/spark/model/dataset"),
    inference_output=Output("OUTPUT")
)
def compute(inference_input_dataset, model_input, inference_output):
    inference_input_df = inference_input_dataset.dataframe()

    path = model_input.filesystem().hadoop_path + '/spark_model'
    model = PipelineModel.load(path)  # This needs to match your model class

    inferences_df = model.transform(inference_input_df)
    inference_output.write_dataframe(inferences_df)
```

Palantir is currently working on how to create a default model serializer for this so that Spark models can be used with models, modeling objectives and deployments directly. I will update this stack overflow post when that is released.

Comment: Appending the Spark ML model file name to the hadoop filepath resolved my issue. psutherland also helped with my help ticket within my organization -- thank you both! I look forward to further developments in this matter, as I enjoyed how `foundry_ml` worked well with Spark ML models in Code Workbooks! It'll be nice to tie those in to Modeling Objectives again.